# GCP stackdriver enteries list pagination issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

i am sending the followin request for enteries list API ,here is the link  to API 
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list

```
{
    "filter": "(jsonPayload.event_type=\"GCE_OPERATION_DONE\" OR  protoPayload.serviceName=\"storage.googleapis.com\" OR protoPayload.serviceName=\"clientauthconfig.googleapis.com\" OR protoPayload.serviceName=\"iam.googleapis.com\" OR protoPayload.serviceName=\"compute.googleapis.com\") AND (jsonPayload.event_subtype=\"compute.instances.insert\" OR jsonPayload.event_subtype=\"compute.instances.delete\" OR protoPayload.methodName=\"storage.buckets.create\" OR protoPayload.methodName=\"storage.buckets.delete\" AND protoPayload.resourceOriginalState.direction=\"EGRESS\" AND protoPayload.request.disabled=true)) AND timestamp>=\"2020-05-16T12:52:00.820Z\" AND timestamp <  \"2020-05-16T13:52:00.820Z\"",
    "resourceNames": [
        "projects/project1"
    ],
    "orderBy": "timestamp desc",
    "pageSize": 1000,
    "pageToken":xxxx"
}
```

I am getting the following respone

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "page_token doesn't match arguments from the request",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

**Can anyone Suggest what  does message imply with an example**

Answer (score 0):

this error is faced when,

the page token of some other project is being used in place of project1

Answer (score 0):

Try to test the API using following format for the requested body and also try without any parameters.

{
  "projectIds": [
    string
  ],
  "resourceNames": [
    string
  ],
  "filter": string,
  "orderBy": string,
  "pageSize": integer,
  "pageToken": string
}